# What is auditing info?

Tags: robocopy

I trying to move files from Server A to server B using robocopy with their NTFS and share permissions. 
Robocopy has an `/copyall` option which should be able to do so, but the account I am using does not seem to have to right to  use this option, but it can do `/copy:DATSO`.  The `U` option, which include auditing info is not included, but what does this information contain? What is the auditing information? and why would i include that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auditing information is what is written to audit log for a file or folder, when any NTFS permission is granted or denied (it is set up separately for permission and action taken (grant/deny)). 
There is no default settings there, so an administrator must explicitly configure them. Usually it is done over sensitive data.
To find audit settings, open file/folder properties, click Security tab, and then click "Advanced" button.

So if you are not sure about this, and didn't set up fileserver yourself, it would probably be good to set flag to copy audit information, if there is any.